# longest and most common word in a given string

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and I want to find both the longest and most common word(s) in a given string.

Say I have this:

```
text = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet amet'

def find_longest_word(word_list):
    longest_word = ''
    for word in word_list:
        if len(word) > len(longest_word)
            longest_word = word
    print(longest_word)
find_longest_word(text.split())
```

This works fine as it finds the longest word. But how do I find both? The longest and the most common?